# Triggering progress-bar animation on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have these labels that represent my skill types, I'm trying to trigger the animation when I hover on *any* one of them.

[image]

## HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 skill-type-build-system ">

    <label class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="text-align: right;">

        <a class="skill-build-system skillType" id="build-system" style="color: #757575;">Build System</a>

    </label>

    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6">

        <div class="meter">
            <span style="background-color: rgb(66, 255, 255); width: 502px; text-align: left;"></span>
        </div>
        
        <div id="collapse-build-system" class="sub-skills" style="display: none">
        </div>

    </div>

    <label class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2" style="text-align: left;">93 %</label>

</div>
```

## I've tried

```
$('.skillType').hover(function(e) {

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#" + id).parent().find(".meter > span").each(function() {
        $(this)
        .data("origWidth", $(this).width())
        .width(0)
        .animate({
            width: $(this).data("origWidth")
        }, 1200);
    });

    console.log('%c id = ' + id, "color: green;");

});
```

I can get my console.log to display the correct elect that I hovered, but the animation doesn't seem to trigger

**Live Set-Up** : (Under Skills)

https://www.bunlongheng.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main problem is that you only went up 1 `.parent()` in the DOM, when you actually needed to go up 2 levels in order for your `.find` to find what you are looking for.

I changed it to `.parent().parent()` to get the wrapping DOM node. But it might be better to just add a class to that wrapping node (like `.skill-container`), then just do a `.closest('.skill-container')` to find the correct node. This is better because if your DOM stucture changes (like a 3rd parent gets added) you won't have to change your javascript. Or if you didn't want to add a new class this might work - `.closest('[class*="skill-type"]')` which will go up the DOM tree until it comes across a node with a class the contains the string "skill-type".

I also changed `.hover` to `.mouseenter` because I only wanted to animation to run when a mouse hover over it, and not when the mouse leaves. `.hover` was firing the animation for mouse enter and mouse leave which felt awkward. but you can change it back if you disagree.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.skillType').mouseenter(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".meter > span").each(function() {
      var w = 0,
        $el = $(this);
          
      if ($.hasData(this)) {
        w = $el.data("origWidth")
      }
      else {
        w = $el.width();
        $el.data("origWidth", w)
      }
      
        $el.width(0)
        .animate({
            width: w
        }, 1200);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.meter {
    height: 10px;
    position: relative;
    background: #555;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-top: 9px;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
}

.meter > span {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 skill-type-build-system ">

    <label class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" style="text-align: right;">

      <a class="skill-build-system skillType" id="build-system" style="color: #757575;">Build System</a>

    </label>

    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-6">

      <div class="meter">
        <span style="background-color: rgb(66, 255, 255); width: 502px; text-align: left;"></span>
      </div>

      <div id="collapse-build-system" class="sub-skills" style="display: none">
      </div>

    </div>

    <label class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2" style="text-align: left;">93 %</label>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, except, when I shake my house over it left-right like 10 times, it shows really short width like this : https://i.imgur.com/9HyaTwk.png

Comment: @cyber8200 I have update the javascript to more a bit more inline with your original attempt. It is now storing the "origWidth" as data and checking for that to animate to. With my previous method if you hover in and out before the animation completed it would mess the width making it become short because it was taking the current width instead of the orignial width. hope that helps

Comment: Thank you so much, it does help a lot. Is it hard to make 93% grow from 0 - 93 as the progress bar animating?